# Pycharm permanently blinking "Updating indices..." in statusbar and html file

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I pasted a video link.
These flashes only occur when HTML files are present.
In Python only case, it did not happen when anaconda only project.
It happens when django's project.

Deleting HTML files stops them.

**Video Link:** [pycharm blinking](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-lHLUtQBTiNkU5hilgq1Pmf9nK2e-Tvg)

**OS:** Windows 10

**Softwares:** 
pycharm version:2017.31build number:py-173.3942.36

python3.6.3 anaconda3 django 2.0.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and consider editing your question because right now it's very low quality and unlikely to receive good answers.